# Arquivo gerado no Android não aparece no windows Explorer

Tags: android, arquivo

Consigo salvar o arquivo no meu micro sd mas se conectar o aparelho celular no 
computador através de uma USB o arquivo não aparece no Windows Explorer.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

public void ExportarArquivoExterno() {

    String lstrNomeArq;
    File arq;
    byte[] dados;

    String txtSalvar = "texto do arquivo";

    try
    {
        //pega o nome do arquivo a ser gravado
        lstrNomeArq = "nomearquivo.txt";

        arq = new File("/storage/external_SD/Exportações", lstrNomeArq);

        FileOutputStream fos;

        //transforma o texto digitado em array de bytes
        dados = txtSalvar.toString().getBytes();

        fos = new FileOutputStream(arq);

        //escreve os dados e fecha o arquivo
        fos.write(dados);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        //trace("Erro : " + e.getMessage());

    }        

}
```

Comment: Alguns arquivos não ficam disponiveis no windows, devido a restrições de acesso do proprio Android.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe existe a possibilidade de alterar essas retrições, são no arquivo ou no android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como pode ser visto  [neste post no Android Stackexchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/46321) e [neste report no google code](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282), este é um bug que, dependendo da forma como o arquivo é criado no aparelho, ele fica inacessivel quando acessado pelo computador, via MTP.

Tente seguir [esta solução retirada do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444859/windows-doesnt-refresh-files-on-android-device-sd-card), ao definir a criação de arquivo no seu aplicativo:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile (this, new String[] {file.toString()}, null, null);
```

Onde `file`  é a variável da URI do seu arquivo, após criado, ou para versoes inferiores a 4.4 ainda é possivel fazer:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Você insere uma das linhas de código logo após ao código de criação do arquivo.

Se quiser mais detalhes, [neste post do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646913/android-how-to-use-mediascannerconnection-scanfile) e [neste aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170214/image-saved-to-sdcard-doesnt-appear-in-androids-gallery-app) há outras sugestões de como contornar esse problema.